# Find last day the password changed in shadow file

Tags: bash

Trying to find the last day the password changed in the shadow file for multiple users.  I can do it on a specific user (user.name) but if the shadow file has more than one user I get a bit stuck.  I don't care about service accounts or any other user (just anyone with user.name e.g. bob.smith, sally.brown, etc.).  If I use a wildcard, then the script blows up.  I am testing this against a dummy shadow.test file (as below).  Any help appreciated.

```
#!/bin/bash
secs_per_day=86400
last_password_change=$(echo $(( $(grep user.name shadow.test |cut -d: -f3) *    
$secs_per_day )))       
date -d@$last_password_change
```

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there. Let's make a shell function out of the code that you wrote:

```
getchangetime() {
    local secs_per_day=86400
    local last_password_change=$(echo $(( $(egrep "${1}" /etc/shadow |cut -d: -f3) *  $secs_per_day )))       
    date -d@$last_password_change
}
```

Then use a for loop to run it for all of the users you care about.

```
for user in $(cut -d: -f1 /etc/passwd| egrep '[a-zA-Z0-9]\.[a-zA-Z0-9]')
do
    echo -n "$user: "
    getchangetime $user
done
```

I'm sure that this could be cleaned up a bit (using bash parameter manipulation instead of cut, and probably a couple of other tweaks) but I think that it will do what you want it to do.

Comment: Thanks, this is perfect.  I didn't think of using a function.  I'm still learning as I go along and this is really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
password_change_dates () {
    secs_per_day=8400 
    while IFS=: read user last ; do
        let last=last*secs_per_day
        printf '%s %s\n' "$user" "$(date -d@$last)"
    done < <(cut -d: -f1,3 "$1" )
}

# user names and password change dates
password_change_dates shadow.test

# just the dates
password_change_dates shadow.test | cut -d' ' -f2-

# just the users
password_change_dates shadow.test | cut -d' ' -f1
```

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason the "passwd -S" command isn't being used?

There's a reason I put that option in Shadow.  Y'all might as well use it :)

Here's the easier way --

```
passwd -S ${USER} | cut -d' ' -f3
```

I don't know if the current maintainer (Shadow is over 21, I threw it out of the house ...) has added support so other databases will support the **-S** option, but I would hope so.

Comment: Answer by the author (sorry to hear the 'why' btw), you kind of need to pick this one :p http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Passwd#History

Comment: I was getting "support" requests well into the '00s (Shadow was written in '87).  When Shadow reached 18, I declared it an "adult" and refused to answer questions.  I then had one person DEMAND I provide him with FREE support.  After all, it was "free" software :)

Comment: I have nightmares about long term support. I often joke when using dates with 4 digit years that this will only work for the next ~8000 years, while being secretly terrified I might somehow be around then and forced to fix them.

Comment: The Shadow maintainers have been doing a fantastic job for the past 18 or 19 years.  I had to stop maintaining Shadow when I started at IBM in '95.  I thought about getting involved in '09 when I left IBM, but I've since moved from software security to power systems management.  It's not clear from your comments if you're a Shadow maintainer.  If you are, thanks for taking care of my "child".  If not, glad to hear you enjoy my software.

Comment: No, not a maintainer, just general developer fears.